# É melhor deixar a lógica no PHP ou Banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, estrutura-de-dados, back-end

Estou criando uma aplicação em conjunto com outra pessoa, ela acha que é melhor colocar toda a lógica do sistema diretamente no banco de dados(MySQL), sob o pretexto de que auxiliará caso utilizemos outras linguagens no futuro e que não haverá necessidade de readaptações na estrutura.

Existirá um sistema, feito em PHP, mas esse, apenas fará requisições de views, e estruturará o front-end.

Qual a melhor opção para o desempenho geral de uma aplicação com grande quantidade de requisições?

Comment: Existe alguma perspectiva de trocar o banco de dados no futuro? Quanto mais se usa o dialeto SQL de um banco, mais difícil migrar pra outro. Se ficar só nas tabelas e na integridade referencial ainda é fácil.

Comment: A tecnologia evolui muito rápido. Ficar preso a algo é suicídio.